# ogr2ogr failed to reproject shapefile error exceeds limits

Tags: shapefile, ogr, coordinate-system

I cannot get correct transformation from WGS84 to the Hungarian EOV EPSG:23700 (Hungarian Datum 72) using ogr2ogr.

I am using ogr2ogr from the fwtools shell. I have a shapefile in GCS WGS84 (epsg 4326) and I want to convert it to EOV, a projected coordinate system using the Hungarian Datum 1972.
The contents of the prj file are:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

When I run this command:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:23700 EOV_HD72.shp WGS84.shp
```

I get failure and the following error:
Error 1:latitude or longitude exceeds limits. Failed to reproject feature 0 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS).

Any suggestions on why this re-projection fails?

Comment: Please provide additional details about the shapefile you are trying to reproject.  If you are getting this type of error, then something is out of bounds.  What are the coordinate extents in both lat and lon of your shapefile?  What is the source of your data?  The prj you listed has the correct contents, so the problem is elsewhere.